# Convergence of Diffusion Equation to Discontinuous Initial Condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've seen a [general proof of this property for continuous functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9yuM.jpg), but it can be generalized to functions with a jump discontinuity by averaging the jump. To that end, I'm attempting it for a particular case.

> Want to show  $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} u(x,t)=\tilde\phi(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ where:
>
> - $u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y) \ dy$
> - $\Phi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi \alpha t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\alpha t}}$ the fundamental solution
> - $\phi(x) =
>   \begin{cases}
>   1,  & \text{if $x\ge0$} \\
>   0, & \text{if $x<0$}
>   \end{cases}$
> - $\tilde\phi(x) =
>   \begin{cases}
>   1,  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
>   1/2, & \text{if $x=0$} \\
>   0, & \text{if $x<0$}
>   \end{cases}$

fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Want to show
$\forall\epsilon>0 \ \exists\delta>0$ such that $t<\delta \implies |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y) \ dy - \tilde\phi(x)|<\epsilon$

because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t) \ dy = 1$ and $\Phi(x-y,t)>0$ we can write

\begin{align}
&= \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y) \ dy - \tilde\phi(x)\right|
\\
&= \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y) \ dy - \tilde\phi(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t) \ dy \ \right|
\\
&= \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y) \ dy - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t)\tilde\phi(x) \ dy \ \right|
\\
& \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(x-y,t) \left| \phi(y) -\tilde\phi(x) \right| \ dy
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to introduce $\delta$ or $\epsilon$.

In the [continuous case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9yuM.jpg), the integral was split into 2 cases:

1. $x$ and $y$ are close: continuity of $\phi$ was used to bound $\left| \phi(y) -\phi(x) \right|$ arbitrarily close to 0.
2. $x$ and $y$ are far: bound on $\phi$ was used to bound $\left| \phi(y) -\phi(x) \right|$. Then the integral of the fundamental solution, with the $x$-close-to-$y$-piece of the domain missing, went to $0$ as $t\to 0$.

I've noticed for this particular case $\left| \phi(y) -\tilde\phi(x) \right|\le 1$, so I could still make use of 2, but I don't know if 1 can be adapted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this isn't what you're looking for because it doesn't seem to generalise, but the proof for $C^0$ functions works at all the continuity points, and at $x=0$ you can directly compute-

$$ u(0,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(0-y)\phi(y)dy = \int_{0}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi \alpha t}}e^{-y^2/4\alpha t} dy = \frac1{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-z^2}dz =\frac12.$$
In particular, $u(0,t) \to \tilde\phi(0)$. A similar calculation [leads to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644731/heat-equation-step-function-initial-condition) an explicit expression for any $x$ in terms of the error function: $
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\mathrm{erf} \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{4t}} \right) \right)
$.

Comment: Hm, I think that this actually does generalise. Because say $x_0$ is the only point of discontinuity of $f$. Then you can write $$ f(x) = [f(x_0^+) - f(x_0^-)]\tilde\phi(x)/2 +[ f(x) -  [f(x_0^+) - f(x_0^-)]\tilde\phi(x)/2 ]$$
the first bit is the same as this one, and the second bit, that's a continuous function now. And you can keep doing this as long as the discontinuities don't accumulate...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand:
$$
\begin{align}
\\
\phi(x) &=[\phi(x_0^+)−\phi(x_0^-)]\tilde\phi(x)/2+[\phi(x)−[\phi(x_0^+)−\phi(x_0^-)]\tilde\phi(x)/2]
\\
\phi(x) &=[1-0]\tilde\phi(x)/2+[\phi(x)−[1-0]\tilde\phi(x)/2]
\\
\phi(x) &=\tilde\phi(x)/2+[\phi(x)−\tilde\phi(x)/2]
\\
\end{align}
$$

I'm not seeing a continuous function here with the way we defined $\phi$ and $\tilde\phi$. Are you suggesting that I use the heaviside function to make a continuous function?

Comment: i was also wondering if I could take an approach like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562742/diffusion-equation-with-a-noncontinuous-auxiliary-condition but without only focusing on $x_0$

Comment: @s0ggyj0hns0n yes, I should have been more careful, I did indeed mean to use a translation of the Heaviside function  (which is I guess $\phi(x-x_0)$), and this is precisely what that link is suggesting to do.